# Return which elements in two numpy arrays are both equal to X value?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, `A = [5, 0, 0, 5]` `B = [5, 5, 0, 5]`

I want to get which elements are equal to 5 in both arrays

The output should be = `[0, 3]`

Comment: How is the output `[0,3]`? Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(np.logical_and(A == 5, B == 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

In one dimensional arrays `np.flatnonzero` works perfectly:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([5, 0, 0, 5])
B = np.array([5, 5, 0, 5])
np.flatnonzero((A == 5) & (B == 5))
```

`np.where` or `np.nonzero`, however, returns tuple and you need to take its first item:

`np.where((A == 5) & (B == 5))[0]` or

`np.nonzero((A == 5) & (B == 5))[0]`

**Output**

```
array([0, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Remark: make sure you converted `A` and `B` to arrays first.